# Get the value from a Registry key

Tags: vb.net, registry

When I try to get a value from Registry and show on a `DataGridView`, the value is not the same as the value that exists in the Registry.

This occurs on `DisplayVersion` and sometimes on `DisplayName` too.

**The values on registry**:

[image]

**The values on my app**:

[image]

My code is:

```
Dim _regKeysFind() As String = {"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
                                "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"}
    Try
        _dTableApps = New DataTable()
        With _dTableApps
            .Columns.Add("Aplicacao")
            .Columns.Add("Versao")
            .Columns.Add("Fabricante")
            .Columns.Add("x64")
        End With
        For Each _regKeyString As String In _regKeysFind
            Using _regKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(_regKeyString)
                For Each _subRegKey As String In _regKey.GetSubKeyNames
                    Try
                        'Get sub keys
                        With _regKey.OpenSubKey(_subRegKey)
                            Dim _name = "", _version As String = "",
                            _installLocation = "", _publisher = "",
                             _systemComponent = "", _releaseType = ""
                            Try
                                Dim _text As New TextBox
                                _text.Text = .GetValue("DisplayName").ToString
                                _name = _text.Text
                                _text = Nothing
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                            Try                                    
                                _version &= .GetValue("DisplayVersion").ToString
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                            Try
                                _installLocation = .GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                            Try
                                _publisher = .GetValue("Publisher").ToString
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                            Try
                                _systemComponent = .GetValue("SystemComponent").ToString
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                            Try
                                _releaseType = .GetValue("ReleaseType").ToString.ToLower
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                            If (_name.ToString <> "" And _systemComponent <> "1" And _releaseType <> "update") Then _dTableApps.Rows.Add({_name.Trim, _version, _publisher.Trim, If(_regKeyString.Contains("6432"), "32", "64") & " bits"})
                            _name = Nothing
                            _installLocation = Nothing
                            _publisher = Nothing
                            _version = Nothing
                            _systemComponent = Nothing
                            _releaseType = Nothing
                        End With
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try
                Next
            End Using
        Next
        With gridAplicacoes
            Try
                _dTableApps = _dTableApps.Select("", "Aplicacao").CopyToDataTable()
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            .DataSource = _dTableApps
        End With           
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    _regKeysFind = Nothing`
```

What can i do to bypass that?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When i put that on MessageBox it shows me the correct value. When i put that on a TextBox, i need to focus on text box and change the value to another thing to show the correct value after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem with code:

```
 Dim _regKeysFind() As String = {"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
        "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"}
    Try
        _dTableApps = New DataTable()
        With _dTableApps
            .Columns.Add("Aplicacao", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("Versao", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("Fabricante", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("x64", GetType(String))
            '.Columns.Add("RegKey", GetType(String))
        End With
        For Each _regKeyString As String In _regKeysFind
            Using _regKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(_regKeyString)
                For Each _subRegKey As String In _regKey.GetSubKeyNames
                    If (_subRegKey IsNot Nothing) Then
                        'Get sub keys
                        With _regKey.OpenSubKey(_subRegKey)
                            Dim _name As String = "", _version As String = "", _installLocation As String = "",
                                _publisher As String = "", _systemComponent As String = "", _releaseType As String = ""
                            Try
                                _name = .GetValue("DisplayName").ToString
                                _name = _name.Split(Chr(0))(0)
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                            Try
                                _version &= .GetValue("DisplayVersion").ToString
                                _version = _version.Split(Chr(0))(0)
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                            Try
                                _installLocation = .GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                            Try
                                _publisher = .GetValue("Publisher").ToString
                                _publisher = _publisher.Split(Chr(0))(0)
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                            Try
                                _systemComponent = .GetValue("SystemComponent").ToString
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                            Try
                                _releaseType = .GetValue("ReleaseType").ToString.ToLower
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                            If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_name) AndAlso _systemComponent <> "1" AndAlso _releaseType <> "update") Then _dTableApps.Rows.Add({_name, _version, _publisher, If(_regKeyString.Contains("6432"), "32", "64") & " bits"})
                            _name = Nothing
                            _installLocation = Nothing
                            _publisher = Nothing
                            _version = Nothing
                            _systemComponent = Nothing
                            _releaseType = Nothing
                        End With
                    End If
                Next
            End Using
        Next
        With gridAplicacoes
            _dTableApps.DefaultView.Sort = _dTableApps.Columns(0).ColumnName & " Asc"
            .DataSource = _dTableApps
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    _regKeysFind = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.
I've added a null check on the `SubKeys` and the `SubKey` itself to the list, so you can verify what `Registry Ke`y you're actually looking at when parsing the list.

I didn't notice any discrepancy between the two references.
Also, notice that the `Registry Keys` you're showing in those picture are not related to the same key.
Use the `SubKey` Guid to find the correct one.

```
Dim RegKeysFind() As String = {"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
                               "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"}
Dim dTableApps As DataTable = New DataTable()
With dTableApps
    .Columns.Add("Aplicacao", GetType(String))
    .Columns.Add("Versao", GetType(String))
    .Columns.Add("Fabricante", GetType(String))
    .Columns.Add("x64", GetType(String))
    .Columns.Add("RegKey", GetType(String))
End With

For Each RegKeyString As String In RegKeysFind
    Try
        Using RegKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegKeyString, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree, RegistryRights.ReadKey)
            For Each SubRegKey As String In RegKey.GetSubKeyNames
                If SubRegKey IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallLocation, Publisher, SystemComponent, ReleaseType As String
                    With RegKey.OpenSubKey(SubRegKey)
                        DisplayName = If(.GetValue("DisplayName") IsNot Nothing, .GetValue("DisplayName").ToString, "")
                        DisplayVersion = If(.GetValue("DisplayVersion") IsNot Nothing, .GetValue("DisplayVersion").ToString, "")
                        If DisplayVersion IsNot Nothing Then
                            Dim FirstWhiteChar As Integer = DisplayVersion.IndexOf(" "c)
                            If FirstWhiteChar > -1 Then
                                DisplayVersion = DisplayVersion.Substring(0, FirstWhiteChar)
                            End If
                        End If
                        InstallLocation = If(.GetValue("InstallLocation") IsNot Nothing, .GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString, "")
                        Publisher = If(.GetValue("Publisher") IsNot Nothing, .GetValue("Publisher").ToString, "")
                        SystemComponent = If(.GetValue("SystemComponent") IsNot Nothing, .GetValue("SystemComponent").ToString, "")
                        ReleaseType = If(.GetValue("ReleaseType") IsNot Nothing, .GetValue("ReleaseType").ToString, "")
                        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DisplayName) AndAlso (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SystemComponent) AndAlso (ReleaseType <> "update"))) Then
                            dTableApps.Rows.Add({DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, If(RegKeyString.Contains("WOW6432Node"), "32", "64") & " bits", SubRegKey})
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            Next
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Throw
    End Try
Next

dTableApps.DefaultView.Sort = dTableApps.Columns(0).ColumnName & " Asc"
gridAplicacoes.DataSource = dTableApps
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but this don't resolve my problem..

When i put this "DisplayName =?.GetValue("DisplayName")?.ToString" give me an error saying "Expression espected".

Values on app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5WMg.jpg

Values on registry: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5WMg.jpg  | When I pass the mouse on "Version" line, the tooltip shows me "19.1": https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoThi.jpg

Comment: We are probably using different version of `VB.Net`. You don't need the `?` to evaluate a nullable. You can handle it with `DisplayName = If(.GetValue("DisplayName") IsNot Nothing, .GetValue("DisplayName").ToString, "")`. Or something like this. -- That tooltip can't render the extra Unicode chars in that string, so they're cut out at the first `\0`. But they're there. I don't have any field like that in any machine registry; anyway, give a moment and I'll make an update to try and solve this.

Comment: Thanks.. When I replace DisplayName = DisplayName.Replace(chr(0), "") it render the same. I will try to split the string when chr(0) as found.

Comment: If you need i send the .reg key to you.

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to. Do you mean that the `DisplayVersion = DisplayVersion.Substring(0, FirstWhiteChar)` is not doing its job? -- Allright, try posting it, lets see what comes out.

Comment: I'll try to do DisplayName = DisplayName.Split(Chr(0))(0), that is, when the string found \0 (tooltip display) I will get the first index (0) of string returned...

Comment: Mind that, yes, I said that the string may contain `\0`, but it could be another non-printable Unicode value. The string should be passed to an Hex Editor (or in Visual Studio) to test it. Or converted using an Unicode Encoding when reversing the `Object` to `String`.

Comment: Problem solved with _version &= .GetValue("DisplayVersion").ToString
_version = _version.Split(Chr(0))(0)

Now i can check if any character in string is printable, if not then split the string with that.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it's sorted out :)

Comment: Thanks for the help... Do you need the .reg file too?

Comment: Well, why not. Post it here (in your question, the editor has a better support for Unicode. PasteBin is ok too). It may suggest a way to avoid similar cases.